# Send an email on behalf a form submitter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form linked to a spreadsheet and every time a person submits a form, we track their email address. I also have a trigger when a user submits a form, it sends an email.

The problem is that all the emails are sent using my email address. I want to send that email using the form submitter email address. How can I achieve that.

I've been working with `GmailApp.sendEmail()` and as options I have:

```
let lastRow = ss.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

const emailFrom = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("FILE_ID", `form responses!B${lastRow}:B${lastRow}`);

const options = {
    htmlBody: message,
    replyTo: data.email,
    cc: emailCc,
    'from': emailFrom 
  };

GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, body, options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the code.

You should replace:

```
const options = {
    htmlBody: message,
    replyTo: data.email,
    cc: emailCc,
    'from': emailFrom 
  };
```

to:

```
const options = {
    htmlBody: message,
    replyTo: data.email,
    cc: emailCc,
    from: emailFrom
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it wasn't the issue, it was related to OAuth scopes, as my script can't send emails on behalf of form submitters if it's not authorized, it seems kind of impossible from the forms perspective, but I'll workaround it, thank you for your answer.